# How much data will maximum into the journey?. when choosing Recurring Schedule as repeat 'every daily' in 1 time

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, schedule, recurring

I have a problem when have 30,000 data. When choosing Recurring Schedule as repeat every daily, there are thousand data into the journey. I would like to know how much Recurring Schedule as repeat 'every daily' will have the maximum amount data number of clear numbers into journey per trip

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stackexchange.
There are no hard limits for contacts entering a journey. however there are guidelines:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000320344&type=1&mode=1

You are far from reaching those. It looks like most of your contacts simply dont fulfill the entry criteria and therefore dont enter into the journey.

Edit: Maybe you should not only check for "false" but also "null"?

Comment: no data not null